# Assign string of values in Python using json

Tags: python, json

```
import requests

headers = {'Authorization': 'token'}
url = "url"
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

My request returns a string of values and I would like to assign each to a variable in `Python`. I'm very new to coding, and have tried a lot of different solutions on here, but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: What does it return?

Comment: {"success":true,"errors":[],"results":[{"skuId":1043421,"lowPrice":28.7500,"lowestShipping":0.00,"lowestListingPrice":28.7500,"marketPrice":56.14,"directLowPrice":null}]}

Comment: And use can use `request.json` to get the JSON from the response

Comment: @AbhigyanJaiswal do you mean `response.json()`?

Comment: @jarmod Yes, I meant that

Comment: Thank you. How can I add that to the code to have the individual values assigned to variables?

Comment: adding print(response.json) gives me <bound method Response.json of <Response [200]>>

Comment: What values from the json would you like to assign to variables?

Comment: It is with the bracket so `response.json()`

Comment: I would like to assign the values for lowPrice to a variable

Comment: Ok, please check the answer I posted

Comment: I received a key error for that one.

Comment: @MarkP Please check again, I edited it

Answer (score 0):

use json.loads():

```
import json
import requests

response = requests.get(...)
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
```

This would convert your text into a dictionary and then you can access values  using the key of the dictionary

Comment: json_data = json.loads(response.text)
NameError: name 'json' is not defined is the error I receive

Comment: you need install json package and import it.

Comment: I installed the json package and receive the same error

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request.json`. So for example:

```
import requests

headers = {'Authorization': 'token'}
url = "url"
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

json = response.json()
low_prices = json["results"][0]["lowPrice"]

print(low_prices)
```

Comment: low_prices = json["results"][0]["low_prices"]
KeyError: 'low_prices'

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests 
import json 

url = 'https://api.covidtracking.com/v1/us/daily.json'

response = requests.get(url)

output = json.loads(response.text)

top5 = output[:5]

for item in top5:   
    print(f'Date - {item["date"]} \t Positive Cases - {item["positive"]} \t Total Test Results - {item["totalTestResults"]}')
```

date, positive and totalTestResults are all keys of the json object received from the api. Yours will be different.

json is a built in package, you should be able to just import it and use. If you are getting error, please upload a screen shot of your code and the error.

Edited: Assign to variables

```
import requests 
import json 

url = 'https://api.covidtracking.com/v1/us/daily.json'

response = requests.get(url)

output = json.loads(response.text)

size = len(output)

date = [None]* size
positive= [None]*size
totalTests = [None]*size 


for i in range(size):
    date[i] = output[i]["date"]
    positive[i] = output[i]["positive"]
    totalTests[i] = output[i]["totalTestResults"]

print(date) 
print(positive)
print(totalTests)
```

Comment: I'm looking at this, and I'm not sure I understand. Will this assign the values to to individual variables?

Comment: No it prints out individual values. You can assign them like this
'date = item["date"]'

Comment: TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

Comment: Updated answer, if you need variables to hold individual elements of the dictionary, you can create them before hand and update them inside the loop